# Cannot send value with CoreBluetooth

Tags: swift, core-bluetooth

I'm trying to write value from central to peripheral through CoreBluetooth, but it doesn't work.
But I get error, that peripheral has no such characteristic, but it has.
Here is CoreBluetooth Extension:

CentralManager:

```
extension MapViewController: CBCentralManagerDelegate {
func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
    switch central.state {
        case .unknown:
            print("central.state is .unknown")
        case .resetting:
            print("central.state is .resetting")
        case .unsupported:
            print("central.state is .unsupported")
        case .unauthorized:
            print("central.state is .unauthorized")
        case .poweredOff:
            print("central.state is .poweredOff")
        case .poweredOn:
            print("central.state is .poweredOn")
          centralManager.scanForPeripherals(withServices: [BLEModels.serviceUUID])
          print ("Started scanning")
        default:
            print("Unknown error for CentralManger.state")
    }
}

func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral,
                    advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
    print(peripheral)
    print("\(String(describing: peripheral.name))")
    availablePeripherals.append(peripheral)
    self.centralManager.connect(peripheral, options: nil)
}

func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
    print("Connected to peripheral!")
    peripheral.delegate = self
    peripheral.discoverServices([BLEModels.serviceUUID])
 }
}
```

PeripheralManager:

```
extension MapViewController: CBPeripheralManagerDelegate {

func peripheralManagerDidUpdateState(_ peripheral: CBPeripheralManager) {
    switch peripheral.state {
      case .unknown:
        print("peripheral.state is .unknown")
      case .resetting:
        print("peripheral.state is .resetting")
      case .unsupported:
        print("peripheral.state is .unsupported")
      case .unauthorized:
        print("peripheral.state is .unauthorized")
      case .poweredOff:
        print("peripheral.state is .poweredOff")
      case .poweredOn:
        print("peripheral.state is .poweredOn")
        peripheralManager.add(likeUService)
        peripheralManager.startAdvertising([CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey:[BLEModels.serviceUUID]])
        print ("Started advertising")

      default:
        print("Unknown error for PeripheralManger.state")
    }
}

func peripheralManager(_ peripheral: CBPeripheralManager, central: CBCentral, didSubscribeTo characteristic: CBCharacteristic) {
    var centrals = self.subscribedCentrals[characteristic, default: [CBCentral]()]
    centrals.append(central)
    print ("Central subscribed")
    self.subscribedCentrals[characteristic]  = centrals
}

func peripheralManager(_ peripheral: CBPeripheralManager, didReceiveWrite requests: [CBATTRequest]) {
    for request in requests{
        let text = String(data: request.value!, encoding: .utf8)
        print (text)
    }
}

func peripheralManager(_ peripheral: CBPeripheralManager, willRestoreState dict: [String : Any]) {
    // Just for using background
 }
}
```

Peripheral:
Here I'm trying to write value in didDiscoverServices.

```
extension MapViewController: CBPeripheralDelegate{

func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: Error?){
    for service in peripheral.services ?? []{
        if service.uuid == BLEModels.serviceUUID{
            if !checkedPeripherals.contains(peripheral){
                checkedPeripherals.append(peripheral)
                newCompanion.peripheral = peripheral
                peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(nil, for: service)
            }
        }
    }
}

func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service:CBService, error: Error?){
    for characteristic in service.characteristics ?? []{
        switch characteristic.uuid{
        case BLEModels.userInfoUUID:
            peripheral.setNotifyValue(true, for: characteristic)
            peripheral.readValue(for: characteristic)
        case BLEModels.descriptionUUID:
            peripheral.readValue(for: characteristic)
        case BLEModels.sendInfoUUID:
            peripheral.setNotifyValue(true, for: characteristic)
            print ("Found send characteristic")
            let data = "Send message".data(using: .utf8)
            peripheral.writeValue(data!, for: sendInfoCharacteristic, type: .withoutResponse)
        default:
            print ("Get unknown type of characteristic")
        }
    }
}

func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didUpdateValueFor characteristic: CBCharacteristic, error: Error?){
    switch characteristic.uuid {
    case BLEModels.userInfoUUID:
        let nameDataStr = String(data: characteristic.value!, encoding: .utf8)
        userTitles.append(nameDataStr!)
        newCompanion.firstName = nameDataStr!
        print ("User info: \(String(describing: nameDataStr)))")
    case BLEModels.descriptionUUID:
        let descrDataStr = String(data: characteristic.value!, encoding: .utf8)
        newCompanion.description = descrDataStr!
    default:
        print("Unknown characteristic")
    }
    if !(addedPeripherals.contains(newCompanion.peripheral!)){
        addedPeripherals.append(newCompanion.peripheral!)
        companions.append(newCompanion)
        print ("Companion added")
        print ("\(companions.count)")
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.usersList.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
}
```

Here my sendInfoCharacteristic:

```
sendInfoCharacteristic = CBMutableCharacteristic(type: BLEModels.sendInfoUUID, properties: [ CBCharacteristicProperties.read, CBCharacteristicProperties.indicate], value: nil, permissions: [CBAttributePermissions.readable] )
```

Here is the error:

```
[CoreBluetooth] WARNING: <CBMutableCharacteristic: 0x283d5e4c0 UUID = 
FF68B080-7028-11EA-BC55-0242AC130003, Value = {length = 20, bytes = 
0xd0af20d182d0b5d0b1d18f20d0b2d0b8d0b6d183}, Properties = 0x4, 
Permissions = 0x2, Descriptors = (null), SubscribedCentrals = (
)> is not a valid characteristic for peripheral <CBPeripheral: 
0x282758000, identifier = 845358A5-0FA5-3009-8939-02B6FA6A43AF, name = 
iPhone, state = connected>
```

And also didSubscribeCentral doesn't work, I made peripheral.SetNotifyValue, but central doesn't subscribe.

I'll be really grateful for some advice.

Comment: In your central you are trying to enable notifications for the sendInfo characteristic, but its declaration doesn't show support for notifications. Notifications for a write-only characteristic are meaningless anyway. You also shouldn't specify a value when you declare a characteristic (value should be `nil`) unless you want a characteristic to have a fixed value that cannot be changed.

Comment: @Paulw11 I specified value as nill while declaring the CBCharacteristic but error still talking that characteristic is not valid for peripheral, error is added in question.

Comment: @Paulw11 and I changed declaration of sendCharacreristic and use setNotifyValue but central doesn't subscribe on it.

Comment: Where is the `sendInfoCharacteristic = ...` line of code?  I assumed it was in your code where you set up your peripheral before publishing it.  Can you show that line of code in context?

Comment: @Paulw11 I showed this line of code in my question after "Here my sendInfoCharacteristic". I declare it before viewDidLoad() as var sendInfoCharacteristic: CBMutableCharacteristic? And then in viewDidiLoad declare it as shown in question.

Comment: @Paulw11 when I use writeValue - I get error that is shown in the end of question. updateValue I cannot use because subscription of central doesn't work inspite of changing sendInfoCharacteristic and using setNotifyValue.

Comment: That is why I am confused. If this code is in your central,  you need to save the characteristic that you discover in `didDiscoverCharacterisitics`, you can't just create an instance of `CBMutableCharacteristic` and write to it. The `CBMutableCharacteristic` should be added to your `likeUsService` on the peripheral side.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212741/discussion-between-georgium-and-paulw11).